# GEE analysis using proc genmod block effect

Tags: r, sas, generalized-estimating-equations

I have done an experiment with two factors in RCBD, bionomail distribution.
I wanna use GEE in Proc Genmod in SAS to analyze the data as follow:

proc genmod data=Emerg; 
class obs Crop Dist Block;
model Emerg/Total = Block Crop Dist Crop*Dist/pscale dist=bin link=logit type3; 
REPEATED subject=obs;
LSMEANS Crop*Dist/pdiff;
output out = AllPred pred = Pred StdReschi = StdResChi ;
run;quit;

It is appreciated if anyone can make a comment or suggestion on this.
Kind Regards
Alireza